# Display Shapefile with leaflet and layer control

Tags: shapefile, leaflet

I try to implement a leaflet pluging, for display a local hosted shapefile. The display of the shapefile work, but i want to add a layer control (for togle shapefile layer).
the plugin link : https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js

the demo link :http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/#3/32.69/10.55

I want to implement the layer control on demo page

```
<script>
var m = L.map('map').setView([0, 0 ], 10);
var watercolor = 
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen 
Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 
3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a 
href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a 
href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'
    }).addTo(m);
    var shpfile = new L.Shapefile('Fr_adm.zip', {
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            if (feature.properties) {
                layer.bindPopup(Object.keys(feature.properties).map(function(k) {
                    return k + ": " + feature.properties[k];
                }).join("<br />"), {
                    maxHeight: 200
                });
            }
        }
    });
    shpfile.addTo(m);
    shpfile.once("data:loaded", function() {
        console.log("finished loaded shapefile");
    });
     // initialize stylable leaflet control widget
var control = L.control.UniForm(null, overlayMaps, {
        collapsed: false,
        position: 'topright'
    }
);
// add control widget to map and html dom.
control.addTo(m);


</script>
```

The shapefile "Fr_adm.zip" is displayed, but no layer control.

Comment: What's the value of your `overlayMaps` variable?

Comment: From the documentation for UniForm plugin https://github.com/chriscalip/L.UniformControl it looks like that after control.addTo(m) you are missing control.renderUniformControl() call.

Answer (score 3):

i see a mistake in the code, no overlayer value. So i try with this :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

//----------------
 var watercolor = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {

        });
     var geo = L.geoJson({features:[]},{onEachFeature:function popUp(f,l){
            var out = [];
            if (f.properties){
                for(var key in f.properties){
                out.push(key+": "+f.properties[key]);
        }
        l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
    }
    }});
     var m = L.map('map', {
    center: [10, -1],
    zoom: 6,
   layers: [watercolor, geo ]
});

//}}).addTo(m);
      var base = 'Fr_admin.zip';
        shp(base).then(function(data){
        geo.addData(data);
        });

    var baseMaps = {
    "BaseLayer": watercolor
};
var overlays = {
        "shapefile": geo
    };
L.control.layers(baseMaps,overlays).addTo(m);




        </script>
```

It 's work, i can chose to display the shapefile or not.
But dont return all segmentation like here :http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/#3/32.69/10.55